# Unable to Promote Component

Tags: web8.5

We have run into an issue when trying to promote a component up to a parent publication. When trying to promote the component, the CME throws the following error:

> Unable to promote
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.R5Blueprinting.CreateExceptionString(FaultException`1
>   exception)    at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.R5Blueprinting.PromoteItem(String id,
>   String destinationRepositoryId, Int32 operationMode)    at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.Blueprinting.PromoteItem(String id, String
>   destinationRepositoryId, Int32 operationMode)    at
>   SyncInvokePromoteItem(Object , Object[] , Object[] )    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

We were able to promote this component in our lower environments, but not in our Production environment.

Originally we thought this error was due to missing mandatory fields that haven't been filled out since updating the component's Schema, but after filling out the missing mandatory fields we are still receiving this error.

We have also ensured that all dependent items have been promoted to the parent publication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue was because of missing versions from the Translated component. We recently performed a purge of our Tridion environments, and when trying to promote the component we saw an error in the Event Viewer that mentions it could not find a version of the translated component that had been purged.

To fix this, we un-localized the translated component, promoted the original component, and then sent the promoted component through translation.

Comment: This is interesting to know. Did you contact SDL Support about it? If so, do you know whether there will be a hotfix to resolve this? If it's not considered a bug (for some reason?) then the messaging should at least be better around it. Thanks for sharing the answer.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, I haven't contacted SDL Support about this yet, but I do plan to. I'll be sure to update this question once I hear back.